# Chain rule method doesn't result with same answer as u-sub. Why?

Tags: calculus

$\int \ln \left(2x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is the integral in question.

I know how to solve it with the chain rule. $\frac{1}{2x}\times 2x = \frac{1}{x}$

But, because I know $u$-sub method, I wish to use it upon this integral.

$\int \ln \left(2x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$

$u = 2x$

$du = 2dx \Rightarrow (1/2)du = dx$

Thus tranforming the integral into: $(1/2)\int \ln u \, \mathrm{d}u$

Which gives us $\frac{1}{2u}$ and undoing the sub results in $\frac{1}{4x}$

Now, this can not be, thus I am at fault and I do not see how.  Please, help explain where I am wrong.

Comment: $\int\ln udu\ne\frac1u$. It's the other way round: $\frac1u$ is the **derivative** of $\ln u$, not the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually integrate something like $\int \ln(2x) \, dx$ by parts, as it is quite efficient.

We use the formula $\int u \,dv=uv-\int v\,du$.

Let

\begin{align*}
u &=\ln(2x) \quad\quad v=x \\
du &=\frac{1}{x}\, dx \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, dv=dx
\end{align*}

Then
\begin{align*}
&uv-\int v\,du \\
=&x\ln(2x)-\int 1 \, dx \\
=&x\ln(2x)-x+c.
\end{align*}

If you were to put yourself in a situation where, after a $u$ substitution, all you had to integrate was $\ln(u)$, you would probably integrate that by parts as well (and then back substitute to the same result if done correctly), thus diminishing your efforts to demonstrate an alternate method.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{1}{2}\int \ln(2x) d2x = \frac{1}{2} \ln(2x)2x - \frac{1}{2}\int2xd\ln(2x) = \frac{\ln(2x)2x}{2} - \int \frac{2x}{x}dx = \frac{\ln(2x)2x}{2} - 2x + C$$